# Is this ok to do in a swift subclass copy()?

Tags: swift, copy, behavior-tree

```
class SubClassType:SuperClassType {    

    override func copy() -> SubClassType {
        return super.copy() as SubClassType
    }
}
```

Note that the super copy is implemented and the SubClassType doesn't add any properties to the super class type, only modifies it's functionality. Really asking because as I was adding support for NSCopying for a behavior tree I typed it in like that and was amazed that the complainer (compiler) didn't get mad at me. I'm so deep in tree structures mentally at this point and not ready to test yet, but kinda wanted to see if it could work or not. Am I overthinking the issue?

Comment: why did you add a return type and didn't return anything ?

Comment: Oops! Made corrections...

Comment: I honestly thought that you had to when returning from NSCopying copy function. Something to do with the NSObject subclass being used in swift. I receive an error since the superclass overrides copy and I need only functional changes in the subclass alone. I was hoping that I could sneak a copy past with same initial data but functionality of the sub class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Your Method

```
override func copy() -> AnyObject {
    let clone = super.copy() as SubClassType
    return clone
}
```

#### My Answer

I'm not sure exactly what you want the method to do.

```
let clone = super.copy() as SubClassType
```

statically types the constant `clone` to be of type `SubClassType`. It doesn't make any changes to the object. The very next line of code

```
return clone
```

statically types the return value to be `AnyObject`. Again, it doesn't make any changes to the object.

The code is identical to

```
override func copy() -> AnyObject {
    return super.copy()
}
```

Which is the default behavior when you don't override a method.

In the end, you have 4 lines of code that are identical to 0 lines of code.

Comment: lol, way overthinking. Ok so I ran a test in playground to flush out what I was attempting and I answered my own question. I'll give you the props and thanks though. You rock!

Comment: "The code is identical to" Not exactly. His code will cause a runtime error when `super.copy()` returns something that is not an instance of `SubClassType`. Yours does not.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A:NSObject {
    var something = "A's something"

    override func copy() ->AnyObject {
        let copy = A()
        copy.something = "A copy's something"
        return copy
    }
}

class SubA:A {

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.something = "SubA something"
    }

    override func copy() ->AnyObject {

        return super.copy() as SubA // error'd: EXC Breakpoint fail!
    }

}


let a = A()
let subA = SubA()

let b = a.copy() as A
let subB = subA.copy() as SubA
```

ok really I was being lazy and didn't want to have to do a deep copy but in the end that say's more about me and code after Thanks Giving dinner.

Answer (score 0):

This fails too.

```
import Cocoa


class A:NSObject {
    var something = "A's something"

    override func copy() ->AnyObject {
        let copy = A()
        copy.something = "A copy's something"
        return copy
    }
}

class SubA:A {

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.something = "SubA something"
    }

    override func copy() ->SubA {

        return super.copy() as SubA
    }

}


let a = A()
let subA = SubA()

let b = a.copy() as A
let subB = subA.copy() as SubA
```